# can't connect to SQL Server from WCF service using account

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wcf

I am trying to connect to sql server from wcf service. Using integrated security, it works fine but when I use an account, it fails. I am able to connect to sqL server management studio using this account. I am not sure what I am missing, do I need another provider to do the access. appreciate any feedback.

```
<add name="GISDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=SVRName;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=GLOBAL\Test;Password=temp"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Am I right that you add Windows credentials to the connection string or is `User ID=GLOBAL\Test;Password=temp` an SQL Server authenticated account? What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: this user is sql server authenticated account. I get the error:   Message "Login failed for user 'GLOBAL\\Test'." string

Comment: Juat to add that following works fine.    <add name="GISDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=SVRname;Initial Catalog=Db;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: Does the user name really contain a backslash? I can't create a SQL Server authenticated account with a backslash (see also parameter login_name http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms189751.aspx). However, `User Id` in the connection string does only take SQL Server authenticated accounts. The error points in the direction that the credentials are not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon the backslash in your account name, I suspect that you are trying to use a windows account in the connection string. There are two kinds of logins that can connect to an SQL Server:

- Windows Logins that are managed in Active Directory and authorized to access a SQL Server instance.
- SQL Server authenticated logins that are managed and authorized in SQL Server management studio.

In a connection string, you can opt to use Windows Authentication (`Integrated Security=SSPI`, you can also use `true` instead of `SSPI`). This means that the application will use the account that the process is running under to connect to the SQL Server. The big advantage of this authentication method is that you do not have to store credentials in the connection string. On the other hand, the only way to change the account that is used is to have the application run under another account (or impersonate in the application each time you connect to SQL Server). So there is no way to set another Windows account in the connection string.

If you want to use a SQL Server authenticated account, you have to add the credentials in the connection string (`User Id=MyUserName;Password=MyPassword`). You can only use an account that has been created at and granted access to the SQL Server instance you try to connect to. By default, a SQL Server instance is configured to only allow Windows authentication, so you might need to enable SQL Authentication first.

Please note that SQL Server authenticated logins cannot contain a backslash - that's the reason for my assumption that you want to use the credentials of a Windows account in the connection string as the username contains a backslash.

So how can you solve the issue:

- If you want to use the Windows account, let your application run under this account. As it is a WCF application, you'd have to change the application pool account if you host it in IIS. Set your connection string to: `Data Source=SVRName;Initial Catalog=db;Integrated Security=SSPI`.
- If you do not want to change the account that the application runs under, create a SQL Server authenticated login at the SQL server and grant it access to the relevant databases. Set the credentials in the connection string: `Data Source=SVRName;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=SQLAuthLogin;Password=SQLAuthPwd`.

Comment: Note that if you add the login/password credentials to your connection string, you'll also have to set `Integrated Security=false` (or simply remove it from the connection string entirely).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Integrated Security=false to your connection string:

```
<add name="GISDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=SVRName;Initial       Catalog=db;Integrated Security=False;User ID=GLOBAL\Test;Password=temp"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: I added but this didnt make any difference. I get the same error. Thanks Jay